# Create an array which contains set of paired_value (key and its value) in mongoDB using java Drive

Tags: java, json, mongodb, bson

I create a MongoDB and I can put data on it, but I cannot make this structure ( I put converted db into JSON format using mongoexport):

```
{
    "main":[
       {
          "name":"E",
          "value":"6"
       },
       {
           "name":"P",
           "value":"1",
       }
    ]
}
```

In fact I want to crate an array which contains set of paired_value of key and its value, for example a pair of "name" and the value which assigned to it.

Before I tested this code:

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
ar.add((new BasicDBObject("name", "e")));
ar.add((new BasicDBObject("value", 6)));
document.put(ar);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
ar.add((new BasicDBObject("name", "e").append("value","6")));
ar.add((new BasicDBObject("name", "p").append("value","1")));
document.put("main",ar);
```